# Blade view not rendering in laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel

I am developing a website where candidate entry has to be done and record search.

I have created a single Blade view file. In which there are different section which are called based on the if condition.

My Display.blade.php view is as below

```
<center>
    @if($ID>0)
        <table border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>@include('Header')</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family:arial;font-size:30px;text-align:center;">Edit Registration</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    @endif

<!--First Call-->
@if($ID < 0)
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>@include('Header')</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-family:arial;font-size:30px;text-align:center;">New Registration1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <form action="/Register" method="post" target="_self">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token() ?>">    
        <table border="1" width="70%" cellpadding="3" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#eeeeee">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name</br><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>

                <td>Middle Name</br><input type="text" name="mname" /></td>

                <td>Last Name</br><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
                <td>Contact No</br><input type="text" name="contactno" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
@endif
</center>
```

Header.blade.php is as below.

```
    <style>
        .container 
        {
             background-image: url("header.jpg");
              background-repeat: repeat-all;
             left:0;
             top:0;
             width:100%;
             height:80px;
        }
 </style>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="Cname">Cube Placement</div>
            <div class="rTable">
                <div class="rTableRow">
                    <div class="rTableHead">
             <strong>
              <a href='{!!url('/Register'); !!}'>Register</a>
             </strong></div>
                    <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Report</strong></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the code execute fine. When Edit Registration section is executed CSS is missing from the page but when New Registration section is called CSS works fine.
except that everything is working correctly.

What is wrong in my code.

Comment: How do you include css in your blade file?

Comment: I have included CSS in the style section in both display.blade and header.blade. as in one if condition css styling do appear but not in another

Comment: You said css is missing from the page. So 'how' do you insert it in both file? Depending on how you insert your assets, it may or may not be reachable from a specific location

Comment: I might have explained it incorrectly sorry for that. I have a header.jpg image included in the Header.blade.php file via css. But the header.jpg file does not included in the Edit Registration

Comment: can you please add the code where you add the css?

Comment: Put the absolute path to that image. Or the full URL. If it doesn't work, show in your code how you put that image.

Comment: I have added the style tag in the main post. location of header.jpg is in public folder of laravel

Comment: First and foremost, try to just display some text without php conditions like that stuffs if it will render the text you inserted on that view. If not then the issue is on your routes or controller

Comment: @claudios : I have checked that. if i only put the first if condition than also my header is not displayed.

Comment: @Kash, does the view displayed without the if conditions?

Comment: '  <table border="0" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>@include('Header')</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="font-family:arial;font-size:30px;text-align:center;">Edit Registration</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
' if i put only this code then also it is not dispalying the header.jpg file

Comment: can you tell me how to put absolute path. My image is in public folder. I might be making mistake

Comment: Check your console for any errors. if you have show them to us

Answer (score 0):

To make your css accessible on every page, place the css file in a folder in the public folder and use this code in the link tag where you call the css file, preferably in the file you load on every page.

```
{{ URL::to('/') }}/path/style.css
```

Here you say to the browser go to yourdomain.com/path/style.css

Hope it works for you